# How do I make a simple count loop in Wordpress Timber(Twigg)?

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

How do I make a simple count loop in Wordpress Timber(Twigg)?

So basically just a loop like this:

```
($i = 0;0 < 3;i++){
echo $test[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
{% for value in test %}
  {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

that is safer than

```
{% for i in 0..2 %}
    {{ test[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

because in second version you have to care about index (is setted? and so on) whereas in the first you don't.
Of course if your final goal is to print only three elements from the array you should consider [slice filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

```
{% for value in test|slice(0, 3) %}
  {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you Don the second is exactly what I needed!  Just need 3 always :)